# Sliding window algorithm for rate limiting requests per second windows

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, rate-limiting

For example, I need to limit requests to service by 1 request per 1 second, requests come as follows:

```
1. 12:00:34.321
2. 12:00:35.231
3. 12:00:35.451
4. 12:00:36.781
```

I store windows as timestamps without millisecond part, but for explanation i'll use seconds as in time specified above.

By receiving request #1, window 34 is created, counter of requests is 1, request is allowed.

By receiving request #2, window 35 is created, counter of requests is to be determined, as we use sliding window, to count the actual requests I do the following calculations:

Determine current sliding window: `(current time - window size(1 second))` which is
`12:00:34.231 - 12:00:35.231`

Window 35 has passed 23% of its size, so we take 77% of requests from previous windows, in our case its the only window - 34. which is 0.77 requests.

Current sliding window rate is 1.77 RPS, which is bigger than allowed - request disallowed.

Seems right so far.

Request #3, new window is not created, counter of requests is to be determined.

Current sliding window: `12:00:34.451 - 12:00:35.451`.

Window 35 has passed 45% of its size, 55% requests is to be taken from previous windows, current RPS is 1.55 - request disallowed.

But it's not right, 1 second window has already passed and request should be allowed.

To mee it seems that I have to associate counters with not windows themselves, but rather some small periods of window for this to work properly (for e.g. 10 periods by 1000 milliseconds)

Is my understanding of the algorithm is wrong? If so, how should it work in my case?

Comment: If it's limited to 1 request per second, you can just note the time of the last request, and then when a new request arrives, compare its time with the time of the previous request.

Comment: If it's limited to *k* requests per second, then you should maintain a queue (first-in first out) of the *k* previous requests, and compare the time of new requests with the time of the first request in the queue.

Comment: Sliding window is not a great way to do rate limiting.  What makes the 1 second time period so special that *that* should be the window length.  Consider token bucket instead: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections
import time


class SlidingWindow:
    TIME = 60  # 10sec
    _CAPACITY = 10
    queue = collections.deque()

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def checkRequest(self):
        while self.queue and self.queue[0]['in_time'] > time.time() - self.TIME:
            self.queue.popleft()
        if len(self.queue) > self._CAPACITY:
            return False
        else:
            self.queue.append({'in_time': time.time()})
```

Comment: If you can add a small explanation on how / why this help resolve the problem that would be nice :)